# C Student Assignment, Array Values Not Passing to Function

Tags: c, arrays

I've been having a problem passing an array to a function. I pass it to one function and update it, then print the values in main, and they print just fine. I pass them to another function to evaluate them, and the values don't make it for some reason. I've tried passing them as const char and const int or just as char and int. They're still not working.

I'm behind on my homework and at wits end with this one. Can you see what I'm doing wrong? I'm compiling in GCC on Ubuntu. As I said, the same loop in main() produces the correct results and I'm passing the array to the function in a way that works fine in an earlier function that sets the values.

In main()

```
evalGuesses(guessType, numberOfGuesses);
```

In evalGuesses()

```
void evalGuesses(char guessType[], int numberOfGuesses)
{
int count;

for(count = 0; count < numberOfGuesses; count++);
{
    printf("\n** Eval: option %c", guessType[count]);
}
return;
} // end evalGuesses
```

Comment: Please show us your complete main() function...

Comment: I'm suspecting you have problems in code you are not showing us. http://ideone.com/msFDhW gives an example of passing an array to a function.

Comment: Thanks, friends, but it was a semicolon after the for() that was causing the problem. I felt stupid until I realized that my eyes weren't the only ones that glossed over it. I've been trying to find that since last night. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get rid of that semi-colon `;` after the closing parenthesis of the `for`. The code you have is equivalent to the following right now:

```
...
for( count = 0; count < numberOfGuesses; count++ ){
    ;   // means "do nothing", empty-statement
}
{
    printf( ... );
}
...
```

Although you seem to be wanting to have `printf( ... );` get looped, in which case you should do as I suggested at the very beginning.

Comment: Haha! That was it! Thanks, ThoAppelsin! I should have caught that but my eyes just glossed over it. Not sure how it got there but thanks very much for catching it!

Comment: @DavidPetersonHarvey No problem bro. *Addition: Though, it makes me wonder how come this same loop works out in `main`, hah*

Comment: And I will add that because you aren't doing anything in the loop by the time you get to your printf() count is going to index one element past the end of your array. Hence the garbage you see in the single printf().

Comment: Well, it was the same loop except for the semicolon. :-)